# Count row and verify only 1 exists Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have:

```
function check_if_loggedin(){
    #get user session id from db.
        $sess = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
    #set numerical value of successfully logged in equal 1
        $loggedInSetSuccess = 1;
    #compare session id to match in db (can only have only 1 match)
        $sessionsDbCompare = $this->db->get_where('Client',array('session_id'=>$sess,'loggedIn'=>$loggedInSetSuccess));

    if($this->db->num_rows($sessionsDbCompare) == 1) {
    # User has valid session(valid sessID+loggedIn=0, show welcome
        #show account settings with primary nav
            $this->load->view('v/supernavigationloggedin.php');
            $this->load->view('v/primarynavigation.php');    
    }
    else{
      # user doesnt have both a valid session and loggedIn is set to 0, show login form
            #show login form with primary nav
            $this->load->view('v/supernavigationnotloggedin.php');
            $this->load->view('v/primarynavigation.php');   
    }  
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows()
```

on the following line:

```
if($this->db->num_rows($sessionsDbCompare) == 1) {
```

I verified that database library is loaded in autoload.php and active record is definitely turned on.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that line to this:

```
if($sessionsDbCompare->num_rows() == 1) {
```